# If $H$ and $K$ are subgroup of $G$ with order $pq$ and $qr$ respecively Then show that $|H \cap K|=q$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $pqr$, where $p,q,r$ are distinct primes.

If $H$ and $K$ are subgroup of $G$ with order $pq$ and $qr$ respecively
Then show that $|H \cap K|=q$

My Attempt
$|H \cap K|$ divides $H$ and $K$
$$\implies |H \cap K| \text{ divides } pq \text{ and }|H \cap K| \text{ divides }qr $$
because $p,q$ and $r$ are distinct primes 
$|H \cap K|=1$ or $|H \cap K|=q$

I am stuck in the case why $|H \cap K| \neq 1$
What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $H\cap K=1$, then by product formula $$|HK|=|H||K|=pq^2r>pqr=|G|$$
But this is a contradiction since $HK\subseteq G$ and we should have $|HK|\leq |G|$.